# Request for T-SQL query

Tags: t-sql

i am new to T-SQL.i want T-SQL query for getting output like below image.I am using MS-Access as Database.

Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciADP.png)

Comment: You should not post images.  You need to post code.

Comment: This post shows absolutely no effort or research on your part.  SO is not a free code writing service.  Do some work to solve your own issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort has been put forth and SO is not a code writing service

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your "question".

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to Pivot. You can use the Pivot Operator are the Jeff Moden style Cross Tab which is described [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/).

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE(Name varchar(100), Salary money, dt date);
INSERT @yourTable VALUES 
('SAM-1',$67,'20161021'),
('SAM-2',$34,'20161021'),
('SAM-1',$39,'20161020'),
('SAM-2',$45,'20161020');

SELECT 
  Name,
  [21-10-2016] = SUM(CASE dt WHEN '20161021' THEN Salary END),
  [20-10-2016] = SUM(CASE dt WHEN '20161020' THEN Salary END)
FROM @yourTable
GROUP BY Name;
```